# "sumo-0.25.0/bin/sumo.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?" error when running veins example

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I am trying to run Veins 4.4 with OMNeT++ 5.0 and Sumo 0.25.0 on Windows 10.
From the veins tutorial, when I tried to run the command

```
/c/.../sumo-0.25.0/bin/sumo.exe -c erlangen.sumo.cfg
```

I got the following message:

> C:/.../sumo-0.25.0/bin/sumo.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory ```

Comment: Can you describe what someone would have to do to get the same error message? Please be as detailed as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried to open sumo.exe in "C:...\sumo-0.25.0\bin" It gave this error message "the code execution cannot proceed because MSVCP.dll was not found".

I reinstalled "Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86)" and also installed "Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x64)"